# Function to rotate bitmap in degrees works pretty fast, but repositions output image

Tags: c, bitmap, rotation, bmp

I've built a good function for rotating bitmaps in degrees.
The problem that occurred after some optimizations is that the output image is getting slightly re-positioned during the rotation.

I've recorded a 360o rotating [video](http://softwarecns.herobo.com/unstable%20motion.mp4) for you to see what do I mean.
And the code as follows:

```
#define OFFSET_OF_ID        (0x0)
#define OFFSET_OF_SIZE      (0x2)
#define OFFSET_OF_PIXELS    (0xA)
#define OFFSET_OF_NDIB      (0xE)
#define OFFSET_OF_WIDTH     (0x12)
#define OFFSET_OF_HEIGHT    (0x16)
#define OFFSET_OF_BPP       (0x1C)
#define OFFSET_OF_NRAW      (0x22)

typedef unsigned char byte, pixel[3];
typedef unsigned short word;
typedef unsigned long dword;
typedef unsigned long long ddword;

byte*
bmp_rotate
(byte *buffer, float angle)
{
    const dword src_width  = *( (dword*)&buffer[OFFSET_OF_WIDTH]);
    const dword src_height = *( (dword*)&buffer[OFFSET_OF_HEIGHT]);
    const dword src_nraw   = *( (dword*)&buffer[OFFSET_OF_NRAW]);
    const dword src_pixels = *( (dword*)&buffer[OFFSET_OF_PIXELS]);
    const dword src_bpp    = *( (dword*)&buffer[OFFSET_OF_BPP]);

    const dword single = src_bpp / 8;
    const dword row = src_width * single;
    dword rowsize = (row % 4) ? (row + 4 - row % 4) : (row);
    byte *dest = calloc( src_pixels + src_nraw, sizeof(byte) );

    double midX, midY;
    int i, j;
    double sin_angle = sin(angle);
    double cos_angle = cos(angle);

    midX = src_width / 2.0f;
    midY = src_height / 2.0f;
    memcpy(dest, buffer, src_pixels);

    for(j = 0; j < src_height; j++)
    {
        dword dest_offset = src_pixels + j * rowsize;
        double deltaY = j - midY;
        double deltaX = 0 - midX;
        double x_computation, y_computation;

        x_computation = midX + deltaX * cos_angle + deltaY * sin_angle + 0.5f;
        y_computation = midY - deltaX * sin_angle + deltaY * cos_angle + 0.5f;


        for(i = 0; i < src_width; i++)
        {
            ddword rotX = x_computation;
            ddword rotY = y_computation;

            if(rotX >= 0 && rotX < src_width && rotY >= 0 && rotY < src_height)
            {
                ddword src_offset  = src_pixels + rotY * rowsize + rotX * single;

                memcpy(&dest[dest_offset], &buffer[src_offset], sizeof(pixel));

            }
            x_computation += cos_angle;
            y_computation -= sin_angle;
            dest_offset += single;
        }
    }
    return dest;
}
```

---

What causes this indecent behavior?

Comment: You don't use anti aliasing so you have some classic problem. When you round value to your pixel grid you have some gap

Comment: Well.. anti aliasing has nothing to do with that problem. Because the same method (thought much less optimized) does just fine. I think you misinterpret the problem. I don't mind the jagging.

Comment: Is you center of the bitmap is the center of the rotation, width and heigh are odd ? Can you try with a cross to highlight the glitch ?

Comment: Side note: `ddword` is an unsigned number, so `rotX >= 0` is inherently true. In order to distinguish between numbers like &minus;0.5 and 0.5, which both yield integer 0, you could check that `x_computation >= 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really see your problem in the video, but I assume that the full 360° rotation is achieved in various partial rotations.

If we look at a 180° rotation, the offset becomes clear: The sine is 0 and the cosine is −1. The rotated coordinates of the top left corner (0,0) is then:

```
x' = xm + (x - xm) * cosa + (y - ym) * sina = xm + xm = w
y' = ym - (x - xm) * sina + (y - ym) * cosa = ym + ym = h
```

The coordinates (w, h) are the exclusive right and bottom borders.

Your working coordinates are real numbers. The integer values describe the left and top coordinates. Converting the (positive) real coords to integers will truncate the fractional part and yield the zero-based pixel indices.

You add 0.5 to your working coordinates in the target space once to enforce proper index calculation. Instead, you should treat the real coordinates of all pixels as the middle of that pixel:

```
x(i) = i + 0.5
y(j) = j + 0.5
```

All your calculations remain correct, except:

```
double deltaY = j + 0.5 - midY;
double deltaX = 0 + 0.5 - midX;

x_computation = midX + deltaX * cos_angle + deltaY * sin_angle;
y_computation = midY - deltaX * sin_angle + deltaY * cos_angle;
```

The idea is to treat pixel coordinates as pixel centres in both source and target space. The correct representation in target space is achieved automatically by rounding towards zero when convering to integer.

Comment: That fixed the thing. Also I maybe had to upload the correct version for comparison as well.. because the displacing is barely noticeable in real life. I am not sure if my English is too bad or I really don't know how to describe it more properly.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a rounding-related problem. I have also faced this kind of problem in my projects in the past. Please check the lines where "integer to other types" or "other types to integer" conversions occur.